# Winforms Bubbling Events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I want to bubble an event from a class to a Custom Usercontrol.
My Usercontrol is basically a datasheet.

```
Sheet
  -> List<Row> Rows
   ->List<Cell> Cells
```

My UC(Sheet) has a list of Rows(Class) with each Row having a list of Cells(Class). My question is.. How can i raise an event from a Cell that the sheet can catch??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cells can raise an event on the sheet, if they are aware of the sheet. For instance:

```
{
   ... some code ...
   Sheet.RaiseCellChanged(this.CellId);
}
```

Of course then each cell must have a way of referencing the sheet that it's on (using a Sheet property in the example above).

Another, more messy, option would be to have the Sheet subscribe to events on all individual cells. That would be more work, but then at least the Cells don't have to be aware of the Sheet they are on.

**EDIT:**
To answer your additional question, performance-wise there wouldn't really be a difference. The code would be easier to write using the first approach, simply also because your Sheet -- or any other object -- would only have to subscribe to a single event to receive data from any changing cell (assuming that that is what you want).

Comment: this would work if i have a way to reference the sheet.. i think il work on that. But may i ask, performance wise, whats better between the two options that you gave??..

Answer (score 0):

It is not really possible in WinForms to bubble events so you probably will need to some functionality on a Sheet level to add/remove a row or a cell.

By making it up to sheet you will be able to subscribe/unsubscribe to events from cells when created/removed and will also be able to hide the internal Sheet's structure/creation process from consumers:

```
public class Sheet
{
    ....

    public void AddRow(object[] values)
    {
        var row = new Row();
        foreach(var val in values) 
        {
           var cell = new Cell(val);
           cell.CellChanged += MyCellChangedHandler;
        }
    }
}

public class Cell
{
    ....

    public Cell(object value)
    {
        var eventProvider = value as IMyEventProvider; //can be anything you want, INotifyPropertyChanges?
        if (eventProvider != null)
            eventProvider.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
    }

    public SomeEventHandler(...)
    {
        if (CellChanged != null) CellChanged(...);
    }
}
```

By doing this you will avoid cells knowing about the sheets and how to call sheets and which methods, etc (it is clearly not their concern), cells just raise events when they change, if anyone listens (sheet) they don't care.